# Where is openapi.yaml file in Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I created a simple Google Cloud Function and would like to [restrict API access with API keys](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys). It says I need to edit `openapi.yaml` file. I am not able to find it.

Where I can find `openapi.yaml` file for Google Cloud project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#endpoints_configure

The file corresponds to a manually-defined OpenAPI (formerly Swagger) definition that describes (in this case) your Cloud Function.

You should be able to use the example shown in that section as the basis for a Open API file specific to your Cloud Function that you will deploy to Service Management.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I tried to create yaml file, but it requires `host` what is `CLOUD_RUN_HOSTNAME `. I checked documentation and google cloud project's info, but I am not able to find where is it. You answered my question, but I am not able to create that configuration file. I am thinking to open new question where to find `CLOUD_RUN_HOSTNAME`.

Comment: In this example from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#deploy_endpoints_proxy), `https://gateway-12345-uc.a.run.app` is the `CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_URL` and `gateway-12345-uc.a.run.app` is the `CLOUD_RUN_HOSTNAME`. You will need to specify this in the `host` field of your Open API yaml, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#endpoints_configure)

Comment: Oh, good call. That's a documentation bug. I've reported it. That represents the hostname for the endpoint and, in the case of Cloud Functions, is something of the form: `REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net`

Comment: @sllopis please fix your documentation.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for help! I am thinking to don't use google cloud for now if it is not documented well.

Comment: Cloud Functions and Cloud Endpoints are both generally available (GA). The combination of using Endpoints to proxy Cloud Functions is "This feature is in a pre-release state and might change or have limited support". I recommend you don't use this in production until it's GA but, both services are individually stable and reliable and so, if you can live with some doc bugs, I think the solution's worth considering

Comment: The comment posted by @sllopis is actually correct: the `host` field of the OpenAPI file should point to ´Cloud_RUN_HOSTNAME´ and not to the Cloud Function's URI (which will correspond to the backend on the `x-google-backend:` `address:` field), since as stated on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#endpoints_configure) the host field will correspond to the API gateway, which in this case will correspond to the Extensible Service Proxy V2 Beta (ESPv2 Beta) deployed in Cloud Run.

Comment: Is there any automated tool that can generate the openAPI yaml file based on the HTTP function cloud? I don't want to write this file my own as i never did it and it is time-consuming for me.