# gcloud throws PERMISSION_DENIED when I try to deploy endpoint configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to [deploy](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#endpoints_configure) endpoint configuration by command:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-functions.yaml \
    --project ESP_PROJECT_ID
```

I got an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Ownership for domain name 'REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net' on project 'PROJECT_ID' cannot be verified.
```

I logged in with command:

```
gcloud auth login
```

This is output in terminal after log in:

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?code_challenge=...

You are now logged in as [user@gmail.com].
Your current project is [PROJECT_ID].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

If I run deploy command again, I got the same error message. What's the issue? Why is PERMISSION_DENIED?

**openapi-functions.yaml**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "send email function."
  title: "send-email"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net"
security:
  - api_key: []
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /send-email:
    get:
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/send-email
        protocol: h2
      responses:
        "200":
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```

If I run:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-functions.yaml --project ESP_PROJECT_ID --verbosity='debug'
```

the output is:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy] with arguments: [--project: "PROJECT_ID", --verbosity: "debug", SERVICE_CONFIG_FILE:1: "[u'openapi-functions.yaml']"]
INFO: No JSON detected in service config. Trying YAML...
DEBUG: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Ownership for domain name 'us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net' on project 'PROJECT_ID' cannot be verified.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dev/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/dev/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/dev/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/endpoints/services/deploy.py", line 350, in Run
    services_util.CreateService(self.service_name, project_id)
  File "/dev/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/endpoints/services_util.py", line 432, in CreateService
    result = client.services.Create(create_request)
  File "/dev/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/servicemanagement/v1/servicemanagement_v1_client.py", line 657, in Create
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/dev/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 731, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/dev/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/dev/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing <https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '403', 'content-length': '218', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sun, 31 May 2020 20:41:07 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Ownership for domain name 'us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net' on project 'PROJECT_ID' cannot be verified.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: What permissions do you have on the project? Also does running either `gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-functions.yaml --project ESP_PROJECT_ID --verbosity='debug'` show any other relevant information as to what might be going wrong with the deployment?

Comment: @DanielOcando thanks for your response. I edited the questions I added the debug output. My personal gmail account is set as a project owner and there si one account `xxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` as editor, `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` as editor and the last memeber `xxx@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as Cloud Functions Service Agent

Comment: I was going through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#endpoints_configure) and user's bhito response is correct, as I was able to successfully follow the tutorial. Notice that Cloud Endpoints will use the prebuilt ESPv2 Beta container deployed to Cloud Run as the API gateway being this the reason why the command fails with the `host:` field set with `REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net` and you receive the 403. I would recommend you to follow the link shared on bhito's answer as the above config will always fail.

Comment: @DanielOcando you are right. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing the wrong host, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#endpoints_configure) says that the host should be the `CLOUD_RUN_HOSTNAME`:

> In the host field, specify `CLOUD_RUN_HOSTNAME`, the hostname portion of the URL that Cloud Run created when you deployed ESPv2 Beta above in Deploying ESPv2 Beta. Don't include the protocol identifier, `https://`

And you are using `host: "REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net"` instead.

Comment: Host value is correct. I was told in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010620/where-is-openapi-yaml-file-in-google-cloud-function) this is a mistake in documentation.